# How to convert audio/video file to SRT?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, subtitles, speech-recognition

I want to convert audio/video file to SRT. I've tried these commands:

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 sample.srt

ffmpeg -threads 4 -i sample.mp4 -vn -an -codec:s:0.2 srt sample.srt
```

But then I learned that it was for extracting the subtitle from already subtitled videos. Is there a way I can **generate** subtitles from mp4/mp3 files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need a tool that does speech-to-text and creates as subtitle file.
This is a very specialized operation.

See the article
[How to Generate Subtitles for Audio and Video? [9 Best Tools]](https://geekflare.com/subtitles-generator/)
for a list of websites and tools, where the first in the list
is YouTube.

Comment: Can you provide me with open-source free tools instead of paid websites?

Comment: Not all are paid, for example YouTube and [Subly](https://www.getsubly.com/) (free for 7 days).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ffmpeg alone does not support speech recognition.

There are some other tools to do that, like [Autosub](https://github.com/crh19970307/AutoSub).